# "At someone's place" vs. "at someone's house" vs. "at someone's"

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences, possessives

Do the three phrases convey the same meaning when we're referring to the place where one lives?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the context is clear, then yes. But context is very important.

Examples where they would not have the same meaning:

- Names of bars, clubs, etc. "We're heading down to O'Connelly's tonight; care to join?" or "They met at Meg's."
- Or basically any other kind of proper noun.

Again, if the context makes it clear that we're talking about residences, you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

The three all convey the same message, but I've always felt strange referring to someone's "house" if it is not in fact a house, but rather an apartment or condominium.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it. I live in an apartment, yet I say things like, "When we get back to the house..." just as often as "home". There are plenty of meanings to the word other than "single family home".